# cannot allocate an object of abstract type

Tags: c++, function, virtual, abstract

In below code snippet , I am getting below error while adding pure virtual function  createImage in
GUIFactory class.

Error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Factory'

Here Factory is not a abstract class, so ideally It should be instantiable. Apart from this if this function is removed and only pure virtual  createButton is added then I am not getting this error which seems to be valid behavior.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
class Button {
public:
    virtual void paint() = 0;
};

class Image {
public:
        virtual void paint() = 0;
};

class OSXButton: public Button {
public:
    void paint() {
        std::cout << "OSX button \n";
    }
};

class WindowsButton: public Button  {
public:
    void paint() {
        std::cout << "Windows button \n";
    }
};

class iPhoneButton: public Button {
public:
    void paint() {
        std::cout << "iPhone button \n";
    }
};

class OSXImage: public Image {
public:
        void paint() {
                std::cout << "OSX button \n";
        }
};

class WindowsImage: public Image  {
public:
        void paint() {
                std::cout << "Windows button \n";
        }
};

class iPhoneImage: public Image {
public:
        void paint() {
                std::cout << "iPhone button \n";
        }
};


class GUIFactory {
public:
    virtual Button *createButton(const char *) = 0;
       virtual Image *createImage(const char *) = 0;//If this function is commented code works fine. 
};

class Factory: public GUIFactory {
public:
    Button *createButton(const char *type) {
        if(strcmp(type,"Windows") == 0) {
            return new WindowsButton;
        }
        else if(strcmp(type,"OSX") == 0) {
            return new OSXButton;
        }

                else if(strcmp(type,"iPhone") == 0) {
                        return new iPhoneButton;
                }
                else
                {

              return NULL;
                }




    }

#if 0
Image *createImage(const char *type) {
                if(strcmp(type,"Windows") == 0) {
                        return new WindowsImage;
                }
                else if(strcmp(type,"OSX") == 0) {
                        return new OSXImage;
                }

                else if(strcmp(type,"iPhone") == 0) {
                        return new iPhoneImage;
                }
                else
                {

              return NULL;
                }




        }

#endif


};

int main()
{
    GUIFactory* guiFactory;
    Button *btn;
        Image *img;

    guiFactory = new Factory;

    btn = guiFactory->createButton("OSX");
        if(btn!=NULL)
        {
    btn -> paint();
        }

    btn = guiFactory->createButton("Windows");
        if(btn!=NULL)
        {
        btn -> paint();
        }

        btn = guiFactory->createButton("iPhone");
        if(btn!=NULL)
        {
        btn-> paint();
        }

        #if 0
        img = guiFactory->createImage("OSX");
        if(img!=NULL)
        {
        img -> paint();
        }

        img = guiFactory->createImage("Windows");
        if(img!=NULL)
        {
        img -> paint();
        }

        img = guiFactory->createImage("iPhone");
        if(img!=NULL)
        {
        img -> paint();
        }




        //btn -> paint();
        #endif
        delete guiFactory;
       // delete Button;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it because of the `#if 0` ? Anyway, that seem a lot of code for a simple error. Maybe this is the reason for the downvotes ?

Comment: It was done intentionally to make my point clear. if I am giving functional declaration, so definition is obvious but I had commented the same to reveal this error :) Without answering question properly downvotes are not acceptable :). I already made my point very clearly that , "Here Factory is not a abstract class, so ideally It should be instantiable. Apart from this if this function is removed and only pure virtual createButton is added then I am not getting this error which seems to be valid behavior"

Comment: Well you should probably edit your question make it extra clear then ("is removed by inserting `if 0...`" ?), since it seems I am not the only one confused. I did not downvote by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `#if 0` and `#endif` around the definition of `createImage`.

Their presence removes the definition, so that `Factory` doesn't override that pure virtual function, and so is still abstract.

Comment: They'll also need to make it a member function.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: It already is (although the indentation is misleading, and the crazy amounts of vertical whitespace makes it even harder to see).

Comment: I have done those changes intentionally. As per my question if function was not defined there, then I should get error like, undefined reference to function or function must be overridden. why compiler is flashing error like:can't allocate an object of abstract type for Factory. even though Factory is not a abstract type.

Comment: It is abstract since, as I said, you haven't overridden all the pure virtual functions. You'd get an "undefined reference" if you declared the override but didn't define it. You have no declaration at all, so the class remains abstract.

Comment: Thanks Mike for update. Does it means if don't override the pure virtual function in derive class then derive class becomes abstract? I believe now it clear so downvotes can be removed from this post.

Comment: @user2997518: Yes, an abstract class is any class with one or more pure virtual functions - either declared in the class itself, or inherited from a base class and not overridden. So a derived class that doesn't override all its base class's pure functions is abstract.